# Oracle doesn't return right Date type value.(with Decode function)

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

Oracle doesn't return a value which I want.

My sql statement is below :

```
select DECODE('2018-06-04','','',to_date('2018-06-04' || ' 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) from dual;
```

I expected return value like this:

```
'2018/06/04 23:59:59'
```

But actually I get this:

```
'2018/06/04'
```

Please tell me the reason of this. And What should I do for a return value that I want.
Someone Help me please.

Comment: What's the purpose of decode here? Just use `to_char` to format dates.

Comment: @Mat I want to insert it into Date Type field in this format..

Comment: Date datatypes store date values in an internal numerical format. If you have strings that represent dates that you need to store, use `to_date` to convert them to the right datatype. And use `to_char` on the query side to format as appropriate.

Comment: One typically would not use DECODE() on a static value